# How to read SNMP variable bindings

Tags: snmp

I am trying to make a snmp trap receiver, that can capture all the incoming snmp trap from UDP 162 port and translate them into meaningful alarms. The image I attached is a sample trap that I captured using wireshark.

[image: SNMP Trap capture]

My script can capture and parse all different parts of the packet, but I got stuck in the variable binding section. Im not sure how I can re-present this section into some user friendly information (that I can show in the user interface). How do I know these sequences are sending something alarming or just some general information regarding the agent node? are these sequences independent information each or together they are forming one piece of information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with any incoming data, it is important to know what kind of info you are getting. The variable bindings of an SNMP trap is basically a hierarchical piece of data. Every object or element represents it's own data. If you take the first element (1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0) you will find that this contains the sysUpTime (see [link](http://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0.html)), which is pretty general.

Most of the other elements seem to start with 1.3.6.1.4.1.4421 which appears to be object from a specific vendor; Santera systems (see [link](http://www.oid-info.com/get/1.3.6.1.4.1.4421)). You might want to try and contact them in order to obtain their MIB (Management Information Base), which should have details on what kind of data is shown in these fields.

It might be possible to find info like this online, have a look at the XML-files on this [link](https://issues.opennms.org/browse/NMS-4549).

Comment: I have their MIB file, I have also extracted all the OIDs from the MIB file. However, how do I know if the trap is a general info or a fault? I can probably guess by the name but how do my script know? does it differ vendor to vendor? or there is a general way? (eg. all OIDs with a specific prefix are critical)

Comment: Once you enter into a specific MIB-file, it's pretty much up to whatever the vendor likes. As far as I know there's no general rules for how one orders information within your own MIB.

Comment: That being said, unless the vendor is a complete idiot, information is generally ordered, basically because the hierarchical nature sort of enforces that. So anything grouped under 1.3.6.1.4.1.4421.2.1.2.2.1 probably is information which is all related.